Excluding category from a filter
I have a PBI table with most observations having a date and some obs not having dates (NULL).
I am applying a relative filter in the view based on this date (date in last xx months), and this is of course excluding from the view all NULL dates observation.
I want to keep these obs in the view though.
Something like SQL date between xx and xx **OR date IS NULL** 
Any help on this?

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Via Power Query or DAX, create a new column of the date or if null use today's date. For example, in DAX as a Calculated Column:
Date with null as today = 
  IF(ISBLANK([YourDate]), TODAY(), [YourDate])

Then use this new column for your Relative Filter.
